# Iteratively inspect multi-resolution data

Tags: python

The `.mcool` files are multi-resolution (e.g., 200,1000,10000,1000000 resolutions), as denoted by the substring after the last `\` delimiter. Analysis for a single `.mcool` file at a single resolution (e.g., 1000000) using [cooltools](https://cooltools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/viz.html) would be:

```
import cooler
import cooltools

data_dir = "./input/"
clr = cooler.Cooler(f'{data_dir}/test.mcool::resolutions/1000000')
chromstarts = []
for i in clr.chromnames:
    print(f'{i} : {clr.extent(i)}')
    chromstarts.append(clr.extent(i)[0])
```

However, now I want to run the analysis for all the resolutions in all the `.mcool` files in the directory.

I want to run `cooler.Cooler(f'{data_dir}/test.mcool::resolutions/1000000')` for each resolution and each file, where j is the resolution..concatenate `j` to the `clr` string. For example, `clr_1000000` if the resolution is 1000000.

```
data_dir = "./input/"
pathlist = Path(data_dir).glob('**/*.mcool')
for path in pathlist:
    
     cool_file = str(path)

     resolution = [i.rsplit("/", 1)[1] for i in cooler.fileops.list_coolers(cool_file)]
    
     ### load a cooler for each resolution 
     for j in resolution:
            clr = cooler.Cooler(f'{cool_file}::resolutions/{j}')
     
            ### make a list of chromosome start/ends in bins
            chromstarts= []
            for i in clr.chromnames:
                print(f'{i} : {clr.extent(i)}')
                chromstarts.append(clr.extent(i)[0])
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [48], in <cell line: 2>()
      2 for path in pathlist:
      4      cool_file = str(path)
----> 6      resolution = [i.rsplit("/", 1)[1] for i in cooler.fileops.list_coolers(cool_file)]
      8      ### load a cooler for each resolution 
      9      for j in resolution:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fileops'
```

Name of files (example):

```
input/A001C019.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
input/A014C038.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
input/A015C006.hg38.nodups.pairs.mcool
```

Resolution of files (example):

```
['/resolutions/1000',
 '/resolutions/10000',
 '/resolutions/100000',
 '/resolutions/1000000']
```

Comment: `cooler.Cooler(f'{cool_file}::resolutions/{j}') = "clr" + j` what do you want to do

Comment: `chromstarts + j = []` is not valid python

Comment: `clr + j.chromnames` what is this

Comment: @rioV8 I want to do `clr = cooler.Cooler(f'{data_dir}/test.mcool::resolutions/1000000')
` for each resolution and each file, where `j` is the resolution..concatenate `j` to the `clr` string. For example, `clr_1000000`

Comment: then why do you write `... = "clr" + j`

Comment: have you run the code through a debugger and inspect the result **AT EACH LINE**

Comment: I meant `"clr" + str(j) = cooler.Cooler(f'{cool_file}::resolutions/{j}')`

Comment: where have you seen an example in Python that constructs a variable name that way, you now have the expression `"clr_1000" = Cooler(...)`, that is illegal Python, why construct the variable name, just use `clr = Cooler(...)`

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: You can't build variable names on the fly.  Instead, use a dictionary.  That's what they're for.